# Decode message $m = p * q$, where $p ^ 5 \bmod N$, $q ^ 5 \bmod N$ and $N$ are known

Tags: encryption, modular-arithmetic

I been going through some cryptography exercises and stumbled across this problem.

> Discover message $m$. You know that $m = p * q$. Also $p ^ 5 \bmod N$,
>   $q ^ 5 \bmod N$ and $N$ are known numbers.

I am really lost and don't know where to start. Could anyone give some hints or point me to right direction where to read up on this problem?

Comment: Do you know the factorization of $N$?  If not (and if $N$ is large enough to make factorization infeasible), this is known to be a hard problem ("the RSA problem")

Comment: @poncho Thank you, that's exactly the case and I can see the RSA in it now. Should I divide it into two problems or will knowing $p ^ 5 mod N$
 and $q ^ 5 mod N$ help in any way?

Comment: No, knowing $p^5 \bmod N$ and $q^5 \bmod N$ doesn't particularly help; given an Oracle that solves your problem, it's easy to use it to solve an arbitrary RSA instance with $e=5$

Comment: And knowing $m^2$ and $p^5$? because you could use the fact that $GCD(2, 5)= 1$ and $GCD(m^2, p^5) = p^2$ ?? Just an idea, not tried

Comment: @ddddavidee: actually, you don't know $p^5$, you know $p^5 \bmod N$; if you know $p^5$ and $q^5$, then it'd be easy (it's easy to take fifth-roots over the integers).

Comment: Do we happen to know anything else? Like, $0\le m<N$? Or some numerical values? Or/and perhaps $m^e\bmod N$ for some known $e$, that is the naked-RSA encryption of $m$ under public key $(N,e)$?

Comment: @fgrieu No unfortunately this is all the info. But there are numerical values for $p ^ 5 mod N$, $q ^ 5 mod N$ and $N$. I just didn't post it as they are big numbers.

Comment: Something could emerge from the values. In particular, if we can factor $N$; or if $(p^5\bmod N)+a\cdot N$ and $(q^5\bmod N)+b\cdot N$ are fifth powers for some guessable $a$ and $b$. Also: either there is no solution, or there an infinity, for $m+i\cdot p\cdot N+j\cdot q\cdot N$ is also a solution when $m$ is; so, at least implicitly, we want the smallest nonnegative $m$, which perhaps the context suggests.

Comment: @fgrieu : $\:$ When the three known values are 3,3,6$\hspace{.02 in}$, 9 is the unique compatible value of m. $\hspace{1.01 in}$

Comment: I find this puzzle incredibly rich: some theoretical aspects of it are hard; and by changing the numerical values, we can vary the techniques required to solve it, and the difficulty. If the source of the puzzle is published, I want to read it!

Comment: @Ricky Demer: A solution for $p^5\bmod N=3$, $q^5\bmod N=3$, $N=6$ is $p=9$, $q=3$, leading to $m=27$. In this particular case, $m=9+18\cdot k$ for $k\in\mathbb Z$. Sorry for so many iterations of this comment before I finally remove much incorrect stuff about the general case, and fix that simple one.

Comment: @user12197 What is $N$? If $N$ is prime, then it's easy to find $\phi(N)$. If $N$ is the product of two large primes, finding $\phi(N)$ is hard.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a full answer yet but here is what I have so far.  Since you know what $p^5 \bmod N$ is and what $q^5 \bmod N$ is then you know what $m^5 \bmod N$ is. Since we also know what $N$ is then we should be able to find out how many times we need multiply $m^5 \bmod N$ by $m^5 \bmod N$ till we get a full cycle (you can calculate it through $\phi(N)$ or you can multiply by m till you get back to your original number).  From that cycle, go back 4 terms and that should be what $m \bmod N$ is.
Update: Finding $\phi(N)$ can be difficult for sufficiently large $N$ but multiplication with mods is a fairly easy cheap.  First make sure that N and 5 are relatively prime, and then (for practicality purposes) repeatedly iterate $F: x\mapsto x^5\bmod N$, starting with the known $x_0=m^5\bmod N$ until $x_{j+1}=x_0$, thus making $x_{j}$ a possible $m$

Comment: This answer is "lets compute $(pq)^5 \bmod N$, and then solve the RSA problem to recover $pq$".  While this is a valid approach (in fact, would appear to be the only reasonable approach unless, as fgrieu has suggested, $p$ and $q$ have been picked to make this easy), there are far better ways to attack the RSA problem (not to mention that you can't multiply $m^5$ by $m$ as you don't know $m$; that's the value we're trying to recover)

Comment: You are right, this is not a real valid approach to solve an RSA problem.  However, since we already know N so we can find out how easy this approach is by finding phi of N (assuming that it is a reasonable number).
*Note* Modified approach to multiply m^5 mod N by m^5 mod N till we get a cycle.

Comment: @Minkus: Finding $\phi(N)$ given $N$ is itself a difficult problem

Comment: Yeah, thats true.  Well, I took a stab at it.  It was a starting point :/

Comment: True that.  I will update my answer to reflect your correction.

Comment: Ha okay fixed.  If you find anything else let me know, I don't want to post a wrong or confusing answer.